# How to populate Twitter Typeahead based on select box value?

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-typeahead

I have an input text that is correctly populate with Twitter Typeahead. In this case i would like to select a value from select box and populate the input text with values that are related with selected dropdownlist value. I found similar questions about my doubt but unfortunatly i didnt get the correct way to solve this:

1. [Dynamically populating Twitter Bootstrap Typeahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829574/dynamically-populating-twitter-bootstrap-typeahead)
2. [Twitter bootstrap Typeahead to populate hrefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957152/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-to-populate-hrefs)
3. [jQuery Autocomplete / Twitter Typeahead Populate Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538591/jquery-autocomplete-twitter-typeahead-populate-multiple-fields)

Below is the code that display a select box that is populate with php code and an input text that is populated with Twitter TypeAhead script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>   

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<br>

<h1>DYNAMIC TWITTER TYPEAHEAD</h1>

<br>
<div class="row">

<?php 
    // Include the database config file 
    include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 

    // Fetch all the category data 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category ASC"; 
    $result = $db->query($query); 
?>


<!-- category dropdown -->
<div class="col-md-4">
<select id="categoryFK" name="categoryFK" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select category</option>
    <?php 
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['categoryID'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Category not available</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

<input type="text" name="products" id="products" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" />

</div>

</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Below is the script that call php script via Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#categoryFK').on('change', function(){
        var queryID = $(this).val();
 if(queryID){
 $('#products').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data: 'query='+queryID,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });
 }
 });
});
</script>
```

And below is the php script (**fetch.php**) that populate values according to categoryID:

```
<?php
//fetch.php
include 'dbConfig.php';
if(!empty($_POST["query"])){ 
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName LIKE '%".$request."%' AND categoryFK = ".$_POST["query"]."
";

$result = $db->query($query); 
$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row["productName"];
 }
 echo json_encode($data);
}
}
?>
```

As i showed the code above, when i type something into input text after i selected any option into select box, the input text with Twitter TypeAhead just populate one register.

In this case, how can i improve php code above to populate input text with values related with select box value correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Below are the scripts that i modified to adapt on my project:

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var products;
        $ ( function ()
        {
            $('#categoryFK').on('change', function(){
                var queryID = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:"fetch.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data: {
                        category: queryID
                    },
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $("#products").val ('');

                        products = data;
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#products').typeahead({
                source: function ( query, result )
                {
                    result ( $.map(products, function (item)
                        {
                            return item;
                        }
                    ));
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
```

And PHP script (**fetch.php**)

```
<?php
include 'dbConfig.php';

if ( isset ( $_POST [ 'category' ] ) ) {
    $request = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["category"]);

    $query = "
        SELECT * FROM products WHERE categoryFK = ".$request."
    ";

    $result = $db->query($query);
    $data = array ();

    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 )
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc ())
        {
            $data[]=$row["productName"];
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
?>
```

Now, with these modifications, i can select an option into "category" select box and after, type into input text where all valus related with selected option will be load :)